# Google Maps Mobile SDK for Business vs. Google Maps Android API

Tags: android, google-maps

We are using google map android api 2.0 for providing map functionality in our android application.
In our application Google map will be used for capturing and showing location on below use cases .

```
 Whenever a client opens the application (from androiddevice ) depending upon location 
 services current location will be captured and using  reverse geocoding process 
 appropriate address will be generated.  

 In reverse flow if any end user wants to enter address manually, using geocoding Service
 appropriate location will be showed on the map.
```

Here are my  questions

1>> What is the `daily map load(api calls) limit for google map android api 2.0` as there is for google map javascript api 3.0(25k map loads per day)?

2>> What is the `geocoding(android.location.Geocoder) limits(No. of geocoding request) per day?`we are not using server side geocoding which limit is 2500 free request per day.Does this limit applies to android geocoding(android.location.Geocoder)?

3>> Our app is for government authority and city citizen will be using it,for that can I use google map android api 2.0 or I have to purchase Google Maps Mobile SDK for Business?

4>> what is the `difference` between `Google Maps Mobile SDK for Business and Google Maps Android API 2.0`?difference in terms of map loads per day and gecoding limits ?

5>> In what `case scenario` I should use Google Maps Mobile SDK for Business and Google Maps Android API 2.0?

Any answer clarifying above questions will be really helpful!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those are great questions to ask... of Google. You can not build on top of a platform and ask for pricing information on a third-party site. What if the answers you get here are wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a GDE for Google Maps (not Googler), and I asked these questions to the Google Maps team before.

1) No limitation for Google Maps Android API v2.
See the Google APIs Console.
[image]

2) I heard no limitation for the `android.location.Geocoder` from Google Maps team,
   because of it's part of Android System.

Read this answer: [Android Geocoder quota limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218764/android-geocoder-quota-limits#17782962)

3) You can use both. But if you want to distribute it without online store, you should contract with the business agreement. Follow the TOS 9.1.2

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1_2

4) There is no support by Google for Google Maps Android API v2.
Read this page.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/

Comment: Oh, I forgot to answer the #5. If you want to receive the support by Google or you don't want to use Google Play Services, you should contract with Google, then use the business SDK. Otherwise, in the most cases, you should use Google Maps Android API v2.

Comment: @ wf9a5m75 Thanks for your Answer,we asked question-2 to google channel partner and  got this answer "Geocoding is not included in the SDK or Android V2,it has to come with a separate license".

Comment: please give me some clarity in above statement,guy is talking about server side geocoding here ???

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is misleading because although the API console shows no limits on the Maps API, **you will be contacted by Google to enable billing or get a Maps for Business licence if the usage of Maps API stays high consistently.**

Here are the differences in the usage quotas between the Google Maps Android API and Google Maps API for Business: https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing

Below are the key differences in the SDK of the two APIs:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/#comparing_versions

P.S. The SDK comparison table above says that Maps for Mobile SDK is available only as a static library, but if you read the previous paragraph on the same page you can see that you can also get the latest  version of Maps for Business SDK through the Android SDK Manager.